# Malloc em uma string, se baseando no tamanho de um FILE

Tags: c, arquivo, ponteiro, malloc

```
int main(void) {

    FILE *p = fopen("matriz.txt","r+");
    char *arquivo;
    arquivo=(char*)malloc(sizeof(p+1)*sizeof(char));

    while (fgets(arquivo,sizeof(arquivo),p)) {
            printf(" %s",arquivo );
    }

}//END
```

o conteudo de matriz.txt :

```
3 3 2 
1 0
1 2
```

Porém o programa não imprime o conteudo, creio que tenha usado incorretamente a alocação de memória, pois ele retorna o tamanho de arquivo como 3, como arrumar esse codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, a função `fopen` não retorna o tamanho do arquivo, veja em [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/). No seu caso, você, inclusive, pode notar que você seta para uma variável do tipo `FILE*`.

Para fazer isto, você deve ler o arquivo todo de alguma forma. No caso, existe uma função que você pode percorrer o arquivo.

Este exemplo abaixo é bem simples mas acredito que vá funcionar para seu caso.

```
int GetFileSize(FILE *f)
{
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); // move para o fim do arquivo
    size = ftell(f); // pega o ponto em que está
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); // volta para o início do arquivo
}
```

Basta chamar `GetFileSize(p)` para receber o tamanho do arquivo.

```
while (fgets(arquivo,sizeof(arquivo),p)) {
        printf(" %s",arquivo );
```

Não faz muito sentido você alocar memória para o arquivo TODO quando você usa apenas cada linha dele. No seu caso, você lê uma linha, associa a `string` com o ponteiro de arquivo. Você lê outra, e associa uma nova string, e não concatena com ela.